# Which temperature is the irreversible Clausius inequality about? (Hotter or colder system? And initial or final?)

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, reversibility

Consider a real-life & physically possible scenario in which heat is exchanged between two **closed** systems at fixed volume. We know that the Clausius inequality for (noncyclic) strictly **irreversible** processes is:

$$
dS > \int{\frac{δQ}{T}}
$$

Since it's a real-life scenario, the two systems necessarily started at different temperatures from each other (otherwise no heat would be exchanged). In addition, if we stop the heat flow after a given $δQ$, the temperature of both systems will necessarily be different from their starting values. So we have a total of 4 different possible values for $T$:

- Initial $T$ of hotter system
- Initial $T$ of colder system
- Final $T$ of hotter system after $δQ$ was exchanged
- Final $T$ of colder system after $δQ$ was exchanged

Which of this $T$ should be plugged in the inequality, if we want to know something about $dS$ of the colder system?

Answer (score 2):

None of the above.  $T$ should be the temperature at the boundary (interface) between the hotter system and the colder system during the transient process that is occurring (i.e., as a function of time during the process).  This is the boundary through which the heat $\delta Q$ is flowing at any time.  So the equation should really be $$\Delta S\geq \int_{t_{\text{initial}}}^{t_{\text{final}}}{\frac{1}{T_B(t)}\frac{\mathrm dQ(t)}{\mathrm dt}\mathrm dt}$$where t is cumulative time during the process and $T_B$ is the temperature at the boundary through which $\mathrm dQ$ is flowing.

Comment: Wouldn't the temperature at the boundary be the initial temperature of the hotter system if the hotter system is an ideal thermal reservoir and the cold system is not (first bullet). Similarly for bullet two?

Comment: @BobD Yes, that would be correct for that special case.

Comment: Thanks. If both systems could be considered ideal thermal reservoirs (relative to the amount of heat being transferred), what temperature would we assign to the boundary? The mean?

Comment: @BobD It's a physically unrealistic situation.  Temperature has to be continuous, so we can't have two different temperatures at the same boundary.  If there are two solids in contact (not ideal reservoirs) and only conduction were occurring, the interface temperature would depend on the conductivity, heat capacity, and density of each solid.  In the case of two ideal reservoirs, we would have to imagine a massless thin conductive slab between them, with a temperature that varies linearly through the slab.  All the entropy generation would occur within the slab.  I would then use the mean.

Comment: Thanks Chet. I know it's unrealistic. For purposes of calculation, if two large bodies have the same mass and specific heat, then the mean seems like the appropriate choice. Take care.

Comment: @BobD Of course, any temperature between the two reservoir temperatures will satisfy the inequality for both reservoirs.

Comment: Thank you, Chet! It blows my mind that I've never seen this explicit formulation on any basic textbook of thermodynamics (TBH it kind of makes me wonder about the state of teaching of the subject). I'd like to know at least a book that elaborates on it: e.g. from it we can see that (I) it's not really heat the subject of our focus, but rather the rate of heat flow and most importantly (II) we're also integrating over T as a function of time (the usual implicit writing of the formula misleads you into thinking we're integrating only over Q, and that T is a function of Q, or worse - a constant).

Comment: The simplified version (assuming contact with constant temperature reservoirs) is in Fermi's book and in Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al.  For the more general case of a boundary temperature that varies both with time and spatial location on the boundary, see the Continuum Mechanics literature (Truesdell and the work out of the Johns Hopkins group).  Here, the integral I is given by$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\int_S{\frac{-q\centerdot n}{T}dS}$$where dS is differential surface of boundary, n is the outward directed normal to the surface, and q is the heat flux vector.